# Header redirection is not working properly

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

Using IIS to host the site locally redirection works fine, however when I place it on my web server the redirection doesn't work.

Below is a segment of the code from my 'myaccount.php' page.

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == true)
{    
    // ... Display page... lots of code here
}
else
// Session not active.
{
    // Redirect to login page.
    header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/2ndassign/login.php");
}
?>
```

---

When that page is hosted online I am simply presented with a blank 'myaccount.php'... no redirection takes place. There is no whitespace present which should cause it to have an error.

So, I've cut my code down to this, so that it's as bare and simple as possible. Error reporting is on so it no longer presents a blank page, but spits out any errors.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
header("Location:http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/2ndassign/login.php");
?>
```

Comment: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/candleso/public_html/2ndassign/myaccount.php:1) in /home/candleso/public_html/2ndassign/myaccount.php on line 4`

Comment: make sure that the code is before the `<head>` section

Comment: I think you printf("somthing") or echo, you must not output any text before the location header   can you show your whole page code till header location? it may be help full.

Answer (score 4):

The error describes the issue

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at   /home/candleso/public_html/2ndassign/myaccount.php:1) in /home/candleso/public_html/2ndassign/myaccount.php on line 4
```

Something is being sent to the browser therefore php can not redirect - even a **white space** or **blank line** will cause this issue. Header must be one of the first things sent to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Try     ob_start();  and  ob_flush();

```
<?php
ob_start(); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
header("Location:http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/2ndassign/login.php");
ob_flush();
?>
```

This will work

Answer (score 1):

the header instruction needs to be one of the first instructions because it can't have any html code before it

Comment: so you can switch the contents of the if else instructions and change the condition with `$_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == false`

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code ,you can check like this also.......................................................

```
<?php 
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] != true)
{    

    // Redirect to login page.
    header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/2ndassign/login.php");
}
else
// Session not active.
{

}
?>
```